# How to get a session context for an office.js content Add In?

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js

In our content add in (PowerPoint) we are using the dialog API for our authentication flow. (The authentication site does not allow to be in an iFrame.)
After that the content will be displayed in an iFrame and the surrounding app does not have any access to the user authentication state.
On all further contents the authentication dialog will just popup and close.

*How may I get a session context for all content add ins in a document from opening to closing it?*

I already tried sessionStorage, localStorage and cookies - but their life times are not in sync with the office session.

Comment: There really isn't an overriding "Office Session". Each add-in operates within its own sandbox/session. What about checking/validating the user is authenticated prior to popping the dialog?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Our app just provides the environment for the login and displays the content in an iFrame. We do not have any information about the user authentication - this is another domain...

Comment: @Marc LaFleur We want to provide a session context for multiple content Add-Ins inside a PowerPoint-Slideshow. So if a user changes a filter inside one content Add-In this should reflect all other content Add-Ins. Without a context inside the client application this can not be realized (when will the session be opened / closed). Any ideas?